# Mysql (MariaDB) acess denied after reboot

Tags: mysql, linux, archlinux, reboot

```
Arch Linux, Mariadb 10.1.21-1.
My commands:
    yaourt -S mariadb
    mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    sudo systemctl start mariadb
    mysql_secure_installation
    yes
    yes
    set root pass
    password
    yes
    yes
    mysql -u root -ppassword
    CREATE DATABASE db;
    CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
    quit;
    mysql -u username -ppassword
    ALL OK!
    quit;
    sudo systemctl stop mariadb;
    sudo shutdown -r now;
    ...
    sudo systemctl start mariadb;
    mysql -u coolone -ppassword;
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'coolone'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: **FLUSH PRIVILEGES;** missed after set GRANT. FUKSH PRIVILEGES write your read your changes new from tables. ROBOOT does the same and you not create a user named **coolone**

Comment: thx, Bernd Buffen, preblem solved!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -ppassword
    CREATE DATABASE db;
    CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```